# Can i create multiple instance of ServicelocatorFactoryBean in spring application?

Tags: spring

There are different functionalities in my application. And for those multiple functionalities, different components are created.
In one of the component(which is created as jar in my war file), say Component A, i have used `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean` for locating services. 
Now i want to use `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean`  in another component, say Component B. On using this in different component also, i am getting :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.kronos.payroll.aggregation.registry.PayrollServiceRegistry' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

This, i am assuming occurs because there is already a `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean`  created in Component A. Can anyone help of what can be done for this ?

In Component A,

```
@Configuration
public class ProductConfig {

    @Bean
    public FactoryBean factoryBean() {
        final ServiceLocatorFactoryBean bean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setServiceLocatorInterface(ServiceRegistry.class);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

In Component B:

```
@Configuration
public class PayrollProductConfig {

    @Bean("payrollServiceRegistry")
    public FactoryBean factoryBean() {
        final ServiceLocatorFactoryBean bean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setServiceLocatorInterface(PayrollServiceRegistry.class);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those classes actual java service api based classes or just normal services? Also chagne the method name to make sure you don't override them and finally make them return `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean` instead of `FactoryBean`.

Comment: Locator services used are java service api based classes. Based on user input, this locator decides which service to call. But why i am getting this error, i am not able to understand?

Comment: as mentuioned, try renaming your methods and return the proper type from the method (the full class not the factory bean).